# Auto-scroll and inputs not displaying on chat box without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a multi user chat application with four files as under:

```
log.html,
index.php,
post.php and 
style.css
```

I have installed these on server (host :megaleech.in) & there are two following concerns that I am facing:

a) chat inputs do not reflect inside chat box when user press the send button, however when I refresh the page then it appears. b) Auto-scrolling not working

You can see it on domain: http://demo.megaleech.in/chting/

Please help in resolving concern.

Thanks in advance.

My codes are as under:

log.html : This is empty file,
style.css: not shown here

index.php is as under:

```
<?php
session_start();
 function loginForm(){
    echo'
    <div id="loginForm">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>
    </div>
    ' ;
}


if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ 

    //Simple exit message
    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'><i>User ". $_SESSION['name'] ." has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
    fclose($fp);

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); 
}
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    loginForm();
}
else{
?>
<doctype html>
<head>
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head></body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>    
    <div id="chatbox"><?php
if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
    $handle = fopen("log.html", "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize("log.html"));
    fclose($handle);

    echo $contents;
}
?></div>

    <form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){



// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    //If user wants to end session
    $("#exit").click(function(){
        var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
        if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}      
    });
});


function loadLog(){     
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height before the request
        $.ajax({
            url: "log.html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div   

                //Auto-scroll           
                var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height after the request
                if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                }               
            },
        });
    }
setInterval("loadLog() ",1000); 


$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });


});
</script>


<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

post.php is as under:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln' id='chat".date("U")."'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the part with getting new messages from the server.

Comment: But it is displaying on page refresh, can you please tell with example what should I write

Comment: If you want to make a chat you should look into websockets, ajax is not really a good way to do it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and use the search ... There are a lot of questions similar to your "issue". You have to search seperate for each small step ... Dynamic loading, content scrooling, etc. and consider @Spokey 's comment ... A polling chat isn't the "right" way if it should be fast.

Comment: BTW, Your `<!DOCTYPE html>` is written wrong and I see it in `body`. The problem is with `setInterval("loadLog() ",1000); ` it can't find the function, try setting `setInterval(loadLog,1000); ` or call it outside of document